# Covariance (OOP) in PHP - how does it work

Tags: php, oop, covariance

```
class Param() {
}
class Subparam extends Param {
}

class Base {

  function mymethod(Param a) {
  }

}

class Sub extends Base {

 function mymethod(Subparam a) {
 }

}
```

In PHP, this leads to a warning: `Declaration should be compatible with Base->mymethod(a : \Param)`

What can I do to prevent that, other than using annotations only?

Comment: You really can't.

Answer (score -1):

You can utilize interface:

```
interface Test {
}
class Param implements Test  {
}
class Subparam extends Param implements Test {
}

class Base {

  function mymethod(Test $a) {
  }

}

class Sub extends Base {

 function mymethod(Test $a) {
 }

}
```

Comment: How does this specify that `Sub::mymethod()` should only be called with a `Param` object?

Comment: There was an error. I changed it :)

Comment: I still don't see how this makes the method covariant.

Comment: Since `Param` implements `Test`, this will allow `$sub->mymethod(new Param)`, which isn't supposed to be allowed.

Comment: This is not covariance.

Answer (score -1):

```
class Param() {
}
class Subparam extends Param {
}

class Base {

  function mymethod(a) {
    // Remove the parameter type from the method declaration.
    if (a !instanceof Param) {
      throw new \Exception('Paramater type should be of 'Param.');
    }

}

class Sub extends Base {

 function mymethod(a) {
 }

}
```

This should get you close.